# adjust heights of two plots (nrow=1) with ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I display two plots in one row with R function ggarrange() so that they have the same dimensions, in particular the same height?

In this example, the second plot is a bit higher than the first plot. I would like to increase the size of a1_plot, so that it matches the size of a2_plot.

```
# required packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)
library(directlabels)
library(ggpubr)

# make dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(first_column=c("value_1","value_2","value_3","value_4","value_4","value_5"),
                  second_column=c("123","123","325","325","656","656"),
                  third_column=c(12,13,1,19,200,360),
                  fourth_column=c(1,124,155,3533,5533,6666))

# plot 1
a1_plot <-
  ggplot(df1, aes(x=third_column, y=fourth_column, colour=second_column)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300)) + 
  ylab("Fourth column")+ xlab("Third column") +
  scale_x_break(breaks = c(210,400)) +
  geom_dl(mapping=aes(x=third_column, y=fourth_column, label=second_column), 
          method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.1), dl.combine("last.points"))) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") 

# plot 2
a2_plot <-
  ggplot(data=df1)+
  geom_point(aes(x=second_column, y=fourth_column) +
  xlab("X axis")+ ylab("Y axis") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")  

# merge plot1 and plot2
ggarrange(print(a1_plot), print(a2_plot), labels = c('a1', 'a2'))
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue you're having. However, the arguments `heights` and `widths` can be used to set the scale of the charts. For example, if you set both to 1 they will both be the same size and square. I think it's more like setting the aspect ratio than literal size.

Comment: If you generate the plots, you can see the grey plot panels being at the exact same height? In my case, the right plot is slightly larger so that the x-axis tick labels are not at the same level in plot 1 and plot 2. I can change the width ratio with the argument "widths". That does not solve my problem. The "heights" argument has no effect at all. Probably because the plots appear in one row.

Comment: The issue seems to be with `scale_x_break(breaks = c(210,400))`. If you add `theme(plot.margin <- unit(c(10, 2, 10, 2), "mm"))` and comment out `scale_x_break(breaks = c(210,400))` the plots are the same height. But I cannot workout how `scale_x_break` affects the plot height or margins.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to change the height of plot 1. By adjusting the margins of plot 2, the problem has been solved.

```
theme(legend.position = "none", plot.margin = unit(x=c(3.6,5,3.9,0), units = "mm"))
```